# Registering a callback in C++ from a joystick device library

Tags: c++, callback, usb, game-engine, joystick

I found a library to handle joystick USB devices in C++ in 
[simple cross-platform gamepad library](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=10675.45) so I am trying to attach the callbacks from it to my application. So it has the following definitions

```
struct Gamepad_device {
    unsigned int deviceID;   
    const char * description;
    int vendorID;

  int productID;

    unsigned int numAxes;
    unsigned int numButtons;
    float * axisStates;
    bool * buttonStates;
    void * privateData;
};

[...]
/* Registers a function to be called whenever a device is attached. The specified
function will be called only during calls to Gamepad_init() and
Gamepad_detectDevices(), in the thread from which those functions were called.
Calling this function with a NULL argument will stop any previously registered
callback from being called subsequently. */
void Gamepad_deviceAttachFunc
   (void (* callback)
   (struct Gamepad_device * device, void * context), void * context);
```

Thus I am trying to attach this function Gamepad_deviceAttachFunc to a private function in my application.

I tried to register my private function `joystickIsAttached (Gamepad_device device)` using

```
Gamepad_deviceAttachFunc(joystickIsAttached(*Gamepad_device));
```

and

```
Gamepad_deviceAttachFunc(joystickIsAttached(*Gamepad_device));
```

but both lead me to

> error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
>        Gamepad_deviceAttachFunc(joystickIsAttached(*Gamepad_device));

or

> error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
>        Gamepad_deviceAttachFunc(joystickIsAttached(Gamepad_device));

**Update**

I also tried to define the called function as

```
void joystickDeviceAttachedCallback
   (struct Gamepad_device * device, void * context);
```

and register the callback using

```
Gamepad_deviceAttachFunc(joystickDeviceAttachedCallback, (void *) 0x1);
```

but this leads to

> error: cannot convert 'MainWindow::joystickDeviceAttachedCallback'
>   from type 'void (MainWindow::)(Gamepad_device*, void*)' to type 'void
>   (*)(Gamepad_device*, void*)'
>            Gamepad_deviceAttachFunc(joystickDeviceAttachedCallback, (void *) 0x1);

Thus what did I do wrong (and how can I fix it?)?

Thanks.

Comment: Should you be passing your struct without the * reference in your defined function, essentially by value instead?

Comment: I tried this too. But no success.

Comment: Could it be because this function is part of the MainWindow class, or so it seems by the error - if it is, maybe you could pull that out of the class?